# How to remove authentication with gpg-agent/git-credentialmanager to pus to a public repo?

Tags: git, gpg, github, gpg-agent, azure

I have a azure devops repository which I have made public recently. Before it was private and I used the git credential manager and gpg-agent.

If I want to push my changes I will get the error:

```
$ git push
```

```
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXX to authenticate.
```

I have followed the instruction and got:

```
fatal: Failed to encrypt file '/home/user/.password-store/git/https/dev.azure.com/<file>.gpg' with gpg. exit=2, out=, err=gpg: rsa3072/YYYYYYY: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
```

How can I solve this, to be able again pushing something to the repository?